# TYPO3 conditional for summer time

Tags: date, conditional-statements, typoscript

Im using a TYPO3 system.

European Summer time bings `March 31` and ends on `October 27`. Is there a way to make a condition in typoscript, either with

```
[condition]
```

of using `if`, to detect if we are between these dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is not possible to nest typoscript conditions I would say no. I recommend to use a user function:

```
<?php

function user_isSummertime() {
  /* check whether it is summertime */
  if ($summertime) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}
?>
```

That goes into your local.conf:

require_once('fileadmin/path/to/script/my_userfunc.php');

```
[userFunc = user_isSummertime()]
  #typoscript
[global]
```

And here I found a php method to check for summertime: [http://phpsnips.com/113/Calculate-Central-European-Summer-Time-(CEST)#.UW1c1aDrFyA](http://phpsnips.com/113/Calculate-Central-European-Summer-Time-%28CEST%29#.UW1c1aDrFyA)